# Lambda package includes pip, setuptools

Tags: python, pip, aws-lambda, virtualenv

I followed [the AWS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) to prepare a deployment package for my `lambda` function. The generated zip file is around 9 - 10MB which includes pip, setuptools, pylint. Are they really required?

Here are the commands.

```
virtualenv v-env
source v-env/bin/activate
pip install xmltodict
pip install requests
deactivate
cd v-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
zip -r9 ../../../../function.zip .
```

Edit: Remove installing boto as it is provided by AWS already

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you may see the guides provide standars and, obviously, guidance for a clean and nice coding or project deployment.

Pylint has a lot of features that help you out while using Python as your programming language, such as checking coding standars, error detection, refactoring help in order to prevend duplicated code, among other tools.

Setuptools is really useful too. Is a development process library designed to facilitate packaging Python projects by enhancing the Python standard library distribution utilities, I encourage you to use it in order to wrap your processes and models in order to have a strong modular project.

And pip is a Package Manager for python packages or modules. You can add, download, delete and a lot more things with it by simple using few words on a line of code. This package manager is useful, you can download wheels, zip's and modules from the internet and easily install them by just using

```
pip install <module or library name>
```

So, by answering your question, if you downloaded and installed a package for AWS supported in Python and it installed those libraries I must think those are being used across the modules you want to use.

You can always check the source code in order to be sure.
If the libraries aren't really being used, they aren't necessary since there are several libraries and packages that do what those libraries do.

Hope it helps, happy coding.

Comment: Those libraries are installed by virtualenv. Also, the lambda package is prepared for deployment, not development.